# FINDSTR to search string in files in a specified set of extensions

Tags: windows

I want to search for a string in files which end with `.asp`, `.config`, and `.txt`. In other words I want to query asp, web.config, or text files for that particular string.

I found that the /G switch doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Moderators: if there is a better way to frame the title for this post, please do so.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1103472#1103472

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
findstr foo *.asp *.config *.txt
```

or

```
findstr /S foo *.asp *.config *.txt
```